# R package development - function aliases

Tags: r, package

I'm developing an R package, and I'd like to set some function aliases, e.g. if I have defined a function named `foo`, I'd like it to be available under `bar` symbol too. Note that I'm aware of `@alias` tag, but that's not what I want. Should I create a new file (probably `aliases.R`) and put all aliases there?

Comment: I think it's better to put them next to the original function: `bar <- foo`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could just define `bar` when you define `foo`.

```
foo <- bar <- function(x, y, z) {
  # function body goes here
}
```

Comment: strangely, I noticed that only `foo()` works. If I reverse `bar <- foo <-`, then only `bar()` works, and it says other function not found. Anyone come across such an issue?

Comment: @rmf: You need to provide more details, in a new question. My guess is that you're using roxygen2 and it only exports the first function.

Answer (score 27):

I found this answer because also ran into the problem where `foo <- bar <- function(x)...` would fail to export `bar` because I was using `royxgen2`. I went straight to the `royxgen2` source code and found their approach:

```r
#' Title
#'
#' @param x 
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' foo("hello")
foo <- function(x) {
    print(x)
}

#' @rdname foo
#' @examples bar("hello")
#' @export
bar <- foo
```

This will automatically do three things:

1. Add `bar` as an alias of `foo` (so no need to use `@alias` tag).
2. Add `bar` to the *Usage* section of `?foo` (so no need to add `@usage` tag).
3. If you provide `@examples` (note the plural) for the alias, it will add the examples to `?foo`.